# ValueError badly formed hexadecimal UUID string django ListView

Tags: python, django, uuid

Assume all imports done.

I have a model like this:

```
class Package(models.Model):
  uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
```

Then I want to use generic `ListView` like so:

```
class PackageList(ListView):
  model = Package
  template_name = 'package/list.html'
```

All with url like so:

```
url(r'^package/list/$', views.PackageList.as_view(), name='package_list'),
```

When I visit the `localhost:8000`, I get 

`ValueError at /package/list/
badly formed hexadecimal UUID string`

However, a `DetailView` generic view loads the detail based on the `uuid` successfully, without any issues.

The error comes up only when using the `ListView`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First thing first, your url says `/package/list/`, but in your question you've mentioned `/travel/list/`. Are you sure you're going to the correct url?

Comment: @kaveh Fixed them now. Was typo in question

Comment: Is this related to your case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445546/django-uuidfield-modelfield-causes-error-in-django-admin-badly-formed-hexadecim

Comment: I followed the step in there, and reset my db, `python manage.py flush`, but still error shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Figured.

The url sequence was the culprit. Having sequence this way fixed it:

```
url(r'^travel/add/$', views.TravelAdd.as_view(), name='travel_add'),
url(r'^travel/list/$', views.TravelList.as_view(), name='travel_list'),
url(r'^travel/(?P<uuid>[\w-]+)/$', views.TravelDetail.as_view(), name='travel_detail'),
```

Previously, it was this:

```
url(r'^travel/add/$', views.TravelAdd.as_view(), name='travel_add'),
url(r'^travel/(?P<uuid>[\w-]+)/$', views.TravelDetail.as_view(), name='travel_detail'),
url(r'^travel/list/$', views.TravelList.as_view(), name='travel_list'),
```

Comment: Right, `list` matches that regexp. You could be stricter with something like `(?P<uuid>[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-...)/$` if you want to avoid worrying about it in the future.